# Airflow GCSToS3Operator: Trasfer just one file with filename

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-storage

I want to send just one file using filename from GCS bucket to S3 bucket using the GCSToS3Operator. I see `delimiter` but it would send all the .csv files. I want just 1 file to sent using the filename. I also see `prefix` option but that takes the prefix bucket path (folders in side the bucket). I have a bucket with no folders but there are multiple files csv files in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix does not necessarily mean the path to the file. Say, for instance, you have a bucket, 'my_bucket' and inside it, you have a object with name `my_dir_1/my_dir_2/my_file.csv`. Note that in Google Cloud Storage, what we know as a path in a typical file system, is part of the object name. Object name is not `my_file.csv`, but `my_dir_1/my_dir_2/my_file.csv`.

Prefixes of this file could be `{my_dir_1', 'my_dir_1/my_dir_2/', 'my_dir_1/my_dir_2/my_file.csv'}`. Note that this last one is the entire object name as is. This is also a valid prefix. Can you try setting the prefix to the whole object name and see if the transfer selects that single file you wish to move?